# Querying all data from MySQL employees sample database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to query all the data from the MySQL Employees sample database. ([structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html) and [row counts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-validation.html))

I'm trying to do this in a way that preserves the relationships between all the tables, but I've never had to query a database this last, and honestly, I'm getting lost in Joins and such. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

---

Edit: SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    `employees`
    LEFT JOIN `salaries`
      ON `employees`.`emp_no` = `salaries`.`emp_no`
    LEFT JOIN `dept_manager`
      ON `employees`.`emp_no` = `dept_manager`.`emp_no`
    LEFT JOIN `titles`
      ON `employees`.`emp_no` = `titles`.`emp_no`,
    JOIN
      `departments` on `departments`
        ON `departments`.`dept_no` = `dept_emp`.`dept_no`

LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Sorry, confused - you talk about extracting the data, and then about joins. Why not just pull each table independently?

Comment: Simply use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason not to, you can do this with mysqldump, as @BenjaminM has already mentioned.

Comment: I'm pulling the entire database, I want to return maybe 100, 200 results at a time - but I want these results to have all of the information in the tables that relate to the employees being selected.

Comment: I do not want to use mysqldump, as I am trying to test performance of MySQL against Cassandra, particularly in regards to selecting data from multiple tables (which Cassandra does not really have to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from -- you can specify fields instead of *
employees e
join salaries s on e.emp_no = s.emp_no,
join titles t on e.emp_no = t.emp_no, 
join dept_emp de on e.emp_no = de.emp_no,depts,
join departments d on d.emp_no = t.emp_no,
join dept_manager dm on d.dept_no = dm.dept_no,
join employees edm on dm.emp_no = edm.emp_no -- second instance of employees to join employee who is a dept manager
```

Comment: Getting "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'join titles t on e.emp_no = t.emp_no,
join dept_emp de on e.emp_no = de.emp_no,' at line 4"

Comment: It was the commas causing the error. However, departments does not have an emp_no - it has a dept_id, which relates to the dept_id on the dept_emp table.

Comment: and after changing the departments part of the query it works! Hurrah! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I should put some information after I added that missing comma. Good luck :)

Comment: it wasn't the missing comma, it was having the commas in there at all. Thanks :) I will mark as answered.

Comment: I had missing (one) comma in my code too :) Now I understand, I see your code has no commas between joins at all.

Answer (score 2):

I try to explain joins simple as possible.

Lets say, we have to store some relational information: person (Name, Surname) and few E-mails assigned to person.

First - we save person information in table persons. We need unique row identifier `personId`, that will allow us to point exact person in persons database.

```
table persons
personId, name, surname
       1, John, Foo
       2, Mike, Bar
```

When we have table like this, we can store persons emails in other table. In this case, creating unique row identifier is not necessary, but its a good practise to store these row identifiers in all tables. PersonId field is telling us what person owns that e-mail.

```
table emails
emailId, personId, address
      1,        1, john.foo@company.com
      2,        1, john.foo@goomail.com
      3,        2, mike.bar@company.com
      4,        2, mike.bar@yaaho.com
```

Now we can select data with join.

```
SELECT persons.Name, persons.Surname, emails.address
FROM 
    persons 
    join
    emails
ON
    persons.personId = emails.personId
```

That query will return data (persons with addresses assigned to them).

```
  John, Foo, john.foo@company.com
  John, Foo, john.foo@goomail.com
  Mike, Bar, mike.bar@company.com
  Mike, Bar, mike.bar@yaaho.com
```

Is that clear?

If joins are not clear for you - maybe visit phpcademy.org or thenewboston.org - they have very good tutorials about many languages and techologies, including SQL.

---

Added later:

You can also join multiple tables, like this:

```
SELECT primarykey, key1,key2, other, fields, detail_t_1.something
FROM
    master_t
JOIN
    detail_t_1 on detail_t_1 
    ON master_t.key1 = detail_t_1.key1,

    detail_t_2 on detail_t_2 
    ON master_t.key2 = detail_t_2.key2
```

---

Added later:

If there are multiple "detail" rows  (like 2 emails in my example) - returned data will contain one person multiple times, with each email address.

In SQL returned data is always in form of table, not tree.

Comment: Thanks.

However, if, like in this database, I have an employees table (key: emp_no), salaries table (key: emp_no), dept_emp (key: emp_no, dept_no) and departments (dept_no), how would I go about joining them? It's that that is giving me the most trouble.

Comment: Oh, and the dept_emp table may have many entries for the same employee, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @jrdnhannah i added some information about multiple joins. Other thing you asked: if there are many "detail" rows for one "master" row - you will get many rows with duplicate master values, but diffrent details (see my "return data" for emails - there is John Foo 2 times, with 2 diffrent emails.

Comment: I've tried that, however the lines with the lowercase "on" seem to be causing syntax errors. I still don't see how that would retrieve data from a table unrelated to the main table, which is instead related through another table (eg `employees` -> `dept_emp` -> `departments`)

Comment: @jrdnhannah please edit question and show your SQL with syntax errors, we will try to fix it.

Comment: I have edited. It's most likely due to me doing something stupid to be honest.